# Responsive table with headers on each row

Tags: css, responsive-design

What I have: 
A responsive table.
When table becomes responsive I remove  table headers ( `th` ) and only show table data (`td`). This can become a problem if data is not self explanatory. So I want to display table headers before each row in the next manner

```
 _______________________
| NAME       Apples     |
|_______________________|
| AMOUNT     10T        |
|_______________________|

 _______________________
| NAME       ORANGES    |
|_______________________|
| AMOUNT     2kg        |
|_______________________|
```

I figured the part where I can use content:attr(headers) to display my headers before my data. Since my headers will be dynamic and I will not hardcode them.

example

```
td:before {
  content: attr(headers);
}
```

The problems I'm having is that it's all janky and not pretty. But I know that I would need to find a way to format that somehow to fit my needs.

Ideal way would be if my headers would take 50% and data 50% of the width.

I want ***css only*** solution.

**DEMO:**

```css
.table-bordered {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table-bordered th {
    text-align: left;
}
.table-bordered th:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.table-bordered th:last-child {
    padding-right: 0;
}
.table-bordered td:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;
}
.table-bordered th, .table-bordered td {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
@media (max-width:768px) {
    .table-bordered thead, .table-bordered tbody, .table-bordered th, .table-bordered td, .table-bordered tr {
        display: block;
    }
    .table-bordered tr {
         margin-bottom: 0.5em;
    }
    .table-bordered th {
        display: none;
    }
    .table-bordered td {
        padding: 0.5em !important;
        border: 1px solid #000;
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="report_artikli" class="table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr><th id="SIF_ART">Sif Art</th><th id="NAZ_ART">Naz Art</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr><td headers="SIF_ART">568846</td><td headers="NAZ_ART">HLAČE 3SA PES PANT /DARK NAVY/BIJELA/</td>
        <tr><td headers="SIF_ART">562588</td><td headers="NAZ_ART">OBUĆA TRČANJE VANQUISH /CRNA/MET.SILVER/</td></tr>
        <tr><td headers="SIF_ART">772442</td><td headers="NAZ_ART">OBUĆA ORIGINALI ANZO LOW /TURF GREY/</td></tr>
        <tr><td headers="SIF_ART">467304</td><td headers="NAZ_ART">OBUĆA ORIGINALI RHYOLITE MID K /TITAN GREY/SKY/</td></tr>
        <tr><td headers="SIF_ART">397385</td><td headers="NAZ_ART">ŠTITNIK +PREDATOR LITE /BIJELA/METALLIC SILVER/</td></tr>
        <tr><td headers="SIF_ART">059850</td><td headers="NAZ_ART">KAPA FEEL A BEANIE /FROST PINK/MEDIUM GREY/</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I actually have something that partially solves the problem.

```
td:before {
    content: attr(headers);
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Problem arises when data column overflows to new line. In that case it will overflow all the way to the left since that height is not taken by my heading.

Comment: Use Bootstrap, it is better than css.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer What? Could you elaborate? Maybe I can replicate what bootstrap is doing.

Comment: Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.Bootstrap makes front-end web development faster and easier. It's made for folks of all skill levels, devices of all shapes, and projects of all sizes.

Comment: You are literally doing nothing to help me solve my problem.

Comment: @HamzaZafeer Don't recommend a framework. This website is about unique programming issues, not a place to advertise frameworks or plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I would use floats and min-height to fix this problem. 
Try the code below.

```
@media (max-width : 768px) {
  table td, .table-bordered td {
    width      : 47%;
    min-height : 30px;
    }
  .table td, .table-bordered td:first-of-type {
    float : left;
    }
  .table td, .table-bordered td:last-of-type {
    float : right;
    }
  .table tr, .table-bordered tr {
    overflow : hidden;
    }
  }
```